# iOS subviews of window not rotating

Tags: ios, rotation, uiwindow

I have a number of subviews on the main window. These subviews do not rotate. Is there an easy way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UIViewController`, it handles rotation automatically. There's rarely the need for adding subviews directly to the window.

Comment: It's because UIViewController supports the delegate with the method `shouldAutoRotate`. I guess it's not easy to implement that method in a view controller outside of the UIVC's scope

Comment: A lot of the logic in my program is messed up. Is there a "hacky" solution to rotate the window?

Comment: You could rotate the views manually by setting their `transform` property (e.g. use `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`).